# What's the conventional way to send commands to running processes?

Tags: sockets, unix, ipc, unix-socket

Is there a conventional way to write a program such that commands can be issued to the program from the command line without a repl? For example, how you can send commands to a running `nginx` server using `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` (or any other valid command besides `restart`)

One idea I had was having the long-running program create and monitor a unix socket that other programs can write to to send it commands.  Another was to create a local server with a REST interface that can be sent commands that way, though that seems a bit gross.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Note that the running program has to be equipped to deal with the messages.  There are many ways to do that, but whatever method chosen has to be coded into the running program.  For example, there isn't a way to make a long-running shell script change its behaviour (other than very crudely by killing it with a signal, or not so crudely by attaching a debugger, but that requires privileges) by trying to communicate with it from another process.  Normally, then, the design of the running program will dictate how you organize things.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are ok, and you could even consider using some [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) machinery, such as making your application serve [JSONRPC](http://jsonrpc.org/) on some [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket. Or use a [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html). Or use [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus).

A common habit on Unix is to have applications reload their configuration files on e.g. `SIGHUP` signal, and save some persistent state (before terminating) on `SIGTERM`. Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (notice that only async-signal-safe routines can be called fro signal handlers; a good way is to only set some `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable inside the handler and test it outside). See also POSIX [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) documentation.

You might make your application become a specialized HTTP server (e.g. using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) and give it some Web interface (or [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), or [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) ...); the user (or sysadmin) will then use his browser to interact with your application.

You could make your server [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) compatible. (I don't know exactly what that requires, it is perhaps D-bus related).

You could embed some command interpreter (like [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) and [Lua](http://lua.org/)) in your app and have some limited kind of [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) loop running on some [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) like a socket or a fifo. Beware of nasty [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Comment: You have also SIGUSR1 and 2 to work in with, which I would suggest in lieu of doing something unexpected with HUP or TERM.

Comment: "systemd compatible" would mean not closing the [FIFO that systemd creates](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/libsystemd-dev/sd-daemon.3.en.html) and passes to your application. It's a sort of local Unix socket and can be used to let `init` know more about your service.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I have a plethora of services running on any number of machines and each is in need of communicating with several others.

My main problem was not so much the communication between the services. That can be done with a simple message sent over a connection (as Basile mentioned, it can be TCP, UDP, Unix sockets, FIFOs...). However, when you have over 20 services, many of which need to communicate with several other services, you start having a headache on how to get all the connections right (I have such a system, although it has a relatively limited number of services, like just 10 and that's already very complicated).

So I created a process (yet another service) called *Communicator*. All services connect to the *Communicator* service and when they need to send a message, they include the name of the service they want to reach. The *Communicator* service is in charge of sending the message to the right place—i.e. it could be to another *Communicator* service running on a different computer. *Communicator* has a graph of all the services available on your network and knows how to send messages to them without your service having to know anything about all of that. Computing a graph can be really complex.

For the purpose, I created the [eventdispatcher](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher) project. It is in C++, which may not be what you're interested in, although you could use it in other languages that interface with C/C++. The structure of the messages are "proprietary" (specific to the *Communicator*), but you can create any message you want. A message includes a name and parameters (`param-name=value`). The first version has a simple one line text communication system. The newer version accepts JSON as well (still must be one line of text per message).

The system supports TCP, UDP, Unix sockets, FIFO, and between threads, you can have thread safe fifos. It also understand signals (like SIGHUP, SIGTERM, etc.) It has a specific connection to listen for the death of a thread. It supports encryption over TCP via OpenSSL. The messages can automatically be dispatched (hence the current name of the library). Connections are assigned a timer. And there are CUI and GUI (Qt) extensions as well.

The one main point here is that all your connections can be polled (see [poll()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)) and thus you can implement a system that reacts to events instead of a system which sleeps and checks for events, sleeps and check, etc. or worth, you have a single blocking connection and everything has to happen on that one connection or your service gets stuck. This is one reason Unix has been using signals since early version of Unix did not have `select()` nor `poll()`.